# Using jp2 aerial photos in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have previously been able to add raster data in the jp2 format to QGIS. I am able to do so on 1.8 installed on my laptop. Unfortunately when I attempt to do this on my desktop, it claims that the file type is unsupported. I installed using the OsGeo installer.

I think I may have missed a setting on the advanced install?

Answer (score 4):

ECW support (which includes JP2) is available in QGIS Lisboa standalone, but not in OSGEo4w anymore due to license issues.
You can still use the standalone version, or install ECW support seperately with gdal latest builds from [this link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php).

I prefer the zipped version, un zipped in a separated directory.
Start Sdkshell.bat to set the environment, then type `gdal_translate -of GTIFF <source>.jp2 <target>.tif` to transform the image to a format QGIS can handle easily.

Sample jp2 files can be found at ftp://ftp.kymartian.ky.gov/FSA_NAIP_2010_1M_UTM/Imagery/

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you need gdal-mrsid package installed to access jp2 files. unfortunatly i dont have any jp2 pictures, so i cant test it.

I have it, 1.9.2 And wont work with my file
(I'm interested to see this working)

currently trying this
http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-gdal-ecw

Answer (score 0):

Although this may add an additional step. As a workaround I installed Lizardtechs's free Geoviewer and import all the images I need for a specific project, then export to a single file.